# Задача по С++ помогите пожалуйста решить подсказать решение

Tags: c++, массивы

Написать программу, осуществляющую умножение двух больших (от 0 до 10^20) чисел.НА С++

ТАкая задача. Можете пожалуйста обьяснить как ее решить. Должен использоваться вектор массив а что дальше после того как его создал. Наставьте на путь.

Comment: Тупо реализуй умножение в столбик, только вместо строчек на бумаге используй вектора цифр.

Comment: boost/multiprecision смотирте.... шутка